# Can Cloud Functions for Firebase execute on user login?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I see how execute a Cloud Function on user account creation:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
```

But I need my function to execute when the user logs in. Is there a `onLogin` trigger?

And can someone with 1500 points create a tag for `firebase-cloud-functions`?

Comment: FYI, the name of the product is "Cloud Functions for Firebase", which is an extension to "Cloud Functions".  The tag for that is google-cloud-functions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no event for login, because only the client side can define exactly when a login happens.  Different clients may define this in different ways.  If you need to trigger something on login, figure out when that point is in your app, then trigger it from the client via a database or HTTP function.

Comment: What about onAuthStateChanged? Is this only available on the client side? Should I have onAuthStateChanged update a location in the database with the 'user' object, and have the Cloud Function trigger from the database update?

Comment: I mean user.uid, not the user object.

Comment: That's a typical way to get user data into the database, and keep it up to date if anything changes.

Comment: This seems possible now: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events

Comment: @chuckles Those triggers have been around for a long time, and neither of them (create nor delete) are relevant to client app sign-in.

Comment: Blocking functions would work in that case as it supports both signup and sign-in.

Comment: What do you mean login is client defined? There are literally signIn and signOut functions in firebase, and auth state events. Why do we have to do it ourselves?

Comment: There are blocking functions for sign in if we turn on GCIP, but for some reason there are no non-blocking ones, so we will take a speed hit https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions

Answer (score 9):

This worked in the controller:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) { // this runs on login
    if (user) { // user is signed in
      console.log("User signed in!");
      $scope.authData = user;
      firebase.database().ref('userLoginEvent').update({'user': user.uid}); // update Firebase database to trigger Cloud Function
    } // end if user is signed in
    else { // User is signed out
      console.log("User signed out.");
    }
  }); // end onAuthStateChanged
```

And this is the trigger in the Cloud Function:

```
exports.getWatsonToken = functions.database.ref('userLoginEvent').onUpdate(event => { // authentication trigger when user logs in
```

I made a location in Firebase Database called `userLoginEvent`.

One confusing bit is that in the functions console it's `/userLoginEvent` but in your code you must leave out the slash.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own analytics event, like `login` and used it as the trigger for your cloud function.

Then in your app, when the user successfully authenticate you use firebase analytics to send an event with the name you defined, like `login`

```
exports.sendCouponOnPurchase = functions.analytics.event('login').onLog((event) => {
  const user = event.user;
  const uid = user.userId; // The user ID set via the setUserId API.


});
```

Comment: This works but please be reminded that analytics events from mobile apps may not be fired in real time.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger an https onCall firebase cloud function on login

ex: This is your login button trigger function which calls an https onCall function after authenticating the user.

```
_login() {
            firebase
                .auth()
                .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
                .then(function (user) {
                    var addMessage = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('myCloudFunctionName');
                    addMessage("whatever variable I want to pass")
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log("I triggered because of an error in addMessage firebase function " + error)
                    )}
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried calling the cloud function after logging out? It still works.

Answer (score 1):

There is also another way you can do this inside Google Cloud if you enable Identity Platform for a project. Then you can follow this guide:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/logging

And trigger cloud functions for any of these Firebase Authentication events:

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/activity-logging?authuser=1&_ga=2.226566175.-360767162.1535709791#logged_operations

The only problem I've just noticed is that the logs generated for Sign In event do not include the firebase app id or anything to determine which client the user logged in on which is really annoying as this was the main reason we needed to do this!