# Cloud Functions: Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'fcm-push'

Tags: node.js, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-firestore, npm-install

I am trying to create a function that send push notification to the device after fetching the device token. The function is deployed properly but the function is getting errors in log. As I mention below the error is

```
cannot find module fcm push
```

I tried:-

```
$ install npm fcm-push
$ install npm fcm-push --save
```

This made no change to the errors.

The function notification is getting this error:-

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":3,"message":"Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.\nDid you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?\nDetailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'fcm-push'\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:476:15)\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:25)\n    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)\n    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/index.js:5:13)\n    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)\n    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)\n    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)"},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"muddasar.pixster@gmail.com"},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction","resourceName":"projects/testingproject-80016/locations/us-central1/functions/Notificaation"}
```

Also I get this

```
 Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'fcm-push'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:476:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:25)
at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/index.js:5:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
```

My package.json is

```
{
"name": "functions",
"description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
"scripts": {
"lint": "eslint .",
"serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
"shell": "firebase functions:shell",
"start": "npm run shell",
"deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
"logs": "firebase functions:log"
},
"dependencies": {
"firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
"firebase-functions": "^2.0.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
"eslint": "^4.12.0",
"eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0"
},
"private": true
 }
```

My code is

```
 'use strict';

 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 exports.Notificaation = functions.firestore.document("Token/{token_id}").onWrite((change, context) => {


console.log('Toekn id', context.params.token_id);

const req = context.params.token_id;

        return admin.firestore().collection('UseData').doc(id).get()
            .then(snapshot => {
                const uid=snapshot.data().user_id;

                console.log("User id: ", uid);



                  return admin.firestore().collection('UserData').doc(uid).collection('Token').doc(req).get()
                  .then(snap=>
                    {


                            if(uid === null)
                            {
                              console.log("You are not logged in");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                               return admin.firestore().collection('UserData').doc(uid).collection('Join_members').get()
                               .then(snap=>
                                 {

                                      snap.forEach(doc =>{

                                         return admin.firestore().collection("Token").doc(doc.data().user).get()
                                            .then(snapshot2 =>
                                              {
                                               const tid2=snapshot2.data().token_id;

                                               console.log(" Token_id: ",tid2);


                                               const payload2= {
                                                   notification:{
                                                       title:"Notification",
                                                       body:"New Message.",


                                                     },

                                                   data:
                                                    {
                                                    user_id:id,

                                                     message:'1',

                                                   }

                                               };
                                                console.log(payload2);

                                               const options = {
                                                     priority: "high",
                                                     timeToLive: 60 * 60 *24,
                                                     content_available: true,
                                                    };




                                                 return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tid2, payload2,options).then(result => {

                                                   var db = admin.firestore();

                                                   var data = {

                                                     type:'New Message Arrived',
                                                     status:1,
                                                     timestamp:admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

                                                   };

                                                   var data1 = {
                                                      notifiction_message:0
                                                   };


                                                   var setDoc = db.collection('UserData').doc(doc.data().user).collection('notification').doc().set(data);

                                                   var setDoc1 = db.collection('UserData').doc(doc.data().user).update(data1);

                                                  return console.log('Notify when New Message ');

                                                 });
                                       });
                                       });
                                       console.log("Sucess");
                                       return true;

                                    });
                            }
                        return true;
                    });
          });
  });
```

Comment: Function is getting deployed but it is not working at instead getting errors

Comment: Can you show the **entire** code of you Cloud Fucntion, with the `require(....);` statements

Comment: Sure.. I am updating my code

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I have updated the code please check it.

Comment: For what do you use the `fcm-push` module? Are you using it (an declaring it) in another function (it is not used in the cloud function of your question)?

Comment: I am not able to get the FCM token id. I am using it to send push notifications to all the device who are logged in

Comment: Apparently you are using the the `fcm-push` module without declaring it. Also it should appear in your `package.json` file under `dependencies`. Are you sure you install it at the correct place?

Comment: yes i have tried installing in root directory as well as function directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180346/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-mudassar-saiyed).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `fcm-push` module in the Cloud Function.

The Cloud Function will only be used to send the notifications.

In order to get the FCM token of the client devices, you should implement a specific code on the client-side.

See the following official Firebase sample where they implement such a mechanism: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications (Version for node 6).

Have a look at the following JS [file](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/public/main.js) where the logic for sending the token is implemented at lines 184 to 211. The code is pasted below for future reference.

In this sample the notification sending is triggered when a user gets a new follower (see the [index.js](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js) Cloud Function file):

```
exports.sendFollowerNotification = functions.database.ref('/followers/{followedUid}/{followerUid}')
.onWrite((change, context) => {})
```

Since you have indicated (in the comments) that you want to send a notification "to users who login to my app", you should create you own trigger mechanism, as there is no out-of-the-box trigger for user signin, see [Can Cloud Functions for Firebase execute on user login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452921/can-cloud-functions-for-firebase-execute-on-user-login).

---

Excerpt of the sample code for the token sending:

```
// Saves the token to the database if available. If not request permissions.
Demo.prototype.saveToken = function() {
  firebase.messaging().getToken().then(function(currentToken) {
    if (currentToken) {
      firebase.database().ref('users/' + this.currentUid + '/notificationTokens/' + currentToken).set(true);
    } else {
      this.requestPermission();
    }
  }.bind(this)).catch(function(err) {
    console.error('Unable to get messaging token.', err);
    if (err.code === 'messaging/permission-default') {
      this.fcmErrorContainer.innerText = 'You have not enabled notifications on this browser. To enable notifications reload the page and allow notifications using the permission dialog.';
    } else if (err.code === 'messaging/notifications-blocked') {
      this.fcmErrorContainer.innerHTML = 'You have blocked notifications on this browser. To enable notifications follow these instructions: <a href="https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/114662?visit_id=1-636150657126357237-2267048771&rd=1&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1">Android Chrome Instructions</a><a href="https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6148059">Desktop Chrome Instructions</a>';
    }
  }.bind(this));
};

// Requests permission to send notifications on this browser.
Demo.prototype.requestPermission = function() {
  console.log('Requesting permission...');
  firebase.messaging().requestPermission().then(function() {
    console.log('Notification permission granted.');
    this.saveToken();
  }.bind(this)).catch(function(err) {
    console.error('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you might have to add it to the dependencies (which is equivalent to local `npm install fcm-push`):

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "fcm-push": "1.1.3"
},
```

and then require it in the code:

```
var FCM = require('fcm-push');
```